# Есть ли возможность вывести из метода изменённые значения?

Tags: java, методы, while, case

Суть в чём, есть переменные и метод, я отправляю эти переменные в метод, они там меняются, но в след раз метод вновь возьмет исходное значение переменных, всё это происходит в цикле, сложно объяснить, но в целом я хочу чтобы числа переменных заходили в метод, там менялись и переменные снаружи тоже меняли значения, и в след раз при использовании метода по циклу он брал те самые изменённые переменные. без метода работает вроде, но если возможность сделать так с методом.

Answer (score 0):

Можно если передать объект ссылка на которую меняться не будет а значения хранящиеся в объекте да.

```
t = new T();
someFunction(t);

....
void someFunction(T t) {
  t.a = 1;
  t.b = "чего душа пожелает";
}
```

Нельзя если вы хотите передать переменную по ссылке (в Java нет такого), чтоб изменить ссылку.

```
... // тут наверное волшебный код его невидно про100
```

А вашем случае я бы возвращал значения из функции и сделал бы рекурсию.

```
x = F(x);
.....

public T F(T t){
   T result = .... // создание нового экземпляра для возврата
   .....// какие-то вычисления 
   return result;
}
```

PS. Примеры абстрактные только для образовательных целей.

Answer (score 0):

Обозначьте переменные которые принимает этот метод как статичные:

```
static int count;

public void countIncrease (){
    count++;
}
```